# C# aggregating attributes in a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object like as shown below

```
public class SampleObject
{
    public int MsfId { get; set; }
    public List<string> PgId { get; set; }
    public List<string> DcId { get; set; }
}
```

In the above aggregation of the `PgId` values grouped by `MsfId`. Same is the case with `DcId` as well.

For example:

```
MsfId: 100
PgId: "abc"
DcId: "123"

MsfId: 100
PgId: "def"
DcId: "456"

MsfId: 100
PgId: "ghi"
DcId: "789"

MsfId: 101
PgId: "abc"
DcId: "123"
```

How to write a LINQ query to aggregate this and create a list of SampleObjects like below?

```
MsfId: 100
PgId: "abc", "def", "ghi"
DcId: "123", "456", "789"

MsfId: 101
PgId: "abc"
DcId: "123"
```

Comment: What exactly would be the grouping criterion? The equality of `MsfId`?

Comment: PgId: "abc" or PgCodes: "abc" ?

Comment: Sounds like a standard `GroupBy` operation, what is the issue?

Comment: do you intend the source to be an `IEnumerable<SampleObject>`?

Answer (score 7):

Try aggregation like this:

```
var result = col.GroupBy(x => x.MsfId)
                .Select(x => new SampleObject {
                       MsfId = x.Key, 
                       PgCodes = x.Select(t=>t.PgId).ToList(),
                       DcCodes = x.Select(t=>t.DcId).ToList()
                });
```

Comment: May need a `.Distinct()` when selecting the `PgCodes` - otherwise I'm betting the OP gets duplicates.

Comment: Extension of the question and if there are other attributes along with MsfId that would also be unique, how can I set them when creating new SampleObject { }

Answer (score 4):

Scenario 1

```
public class SampleObject
{
    public int MsfId { get; set; }
    public List<string> PgId { get; set; }
    public List<string> DcId { get; set; }
}
```

Scenario 2

```
public class SampleObjectSource
{
    public int MsfId { get; set; }
    public string PgId { get; set; }
    public string DcId { get; set; }
}
```

**Scenario 1 Answer**

```
   var collection = new List<SampleObject>();
   var result = collection.GroupBy(y => y.MsfId)
                    .Select(y => new SampleObject
                    {
                        MsfId = y.Key,
                        PgId = y.SelectMany(g => g.PgId).Distinct().ToList(),
                    }).ToList();
```

**Scenario 2**

```
var collection2 = new List<SampleObjectSource>();
var result1 = collection2.GroupBy(y => y.MsfId)
              .Select(y => new SampleObject
              {
                  MsfId = y.Key,
                  PgId = y.Select(h => h.PgId).Distinct().ToList(),
              }).ToList();
```

**Update : Please see the [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1gUeuu)**

Comment: This does not work because `SelectMany(p => p.PgId)` returns an `IEnumerable<char>`. Test your solution before posting please.

Comment: @Abbondanza here `PgId` is         public List<string> PgId { get; set; } if you wont SelectMany u will get Collection of list

Comment: You misunderstood the question. Input is a `List<A>` where `A` is `{int MsfId, string PgId, string DcId}`, not `{int MsfId, List<string> PgId, List<string> DcId}`. Only in the output `PgId` and `DcId` are indeed `List<string>`s.

Comment: @Abbondanza, no, its entirely possible you are misunderstanding the question, unless you are the OP or omniscient then you may be entirely wrong.

Comment: Yes i get it, Thanks .

Answer (score 3):

You need to group the items with a query. *This linq grouping will create a collection of collections(with a key)*

I just made a full working example:

```
// The class to start with
public class SampleObjectSource
{
    public int MsfId { get; set; }
    public string PgId { get; set; }
    public string DcId { get; set; }
}

// the result class
public class SampleObject
{
    public int MsfId { get; set; }
    public List<string> PgId { get; set; }
    public List<string> DcId { get; set; }
}

// for example:
public class Example
{
    public Example()
    {
        // create a list that contains the items.
        var list = new List<SampleObjectSource>
        {
            new SampleObjectSource { MsfId= 100, PgId=  "abc", DcId= "123" },
            new SampleObjectSource { MsfId= 100, PgId=  "def", DcId= "456" },
            new SampleObjectSource { MsfId= 100, PgId=  "ghi", DcId= "789" },
            new SampleObjectSource { MsfId= 101, PgId=  "abc", DcId= "123" },
        };

        // the linq query that does the grouping.
        var query = from item in list
                    // group the items by MsfId
                    group item by item.MsfId into itemgroup
                    // create the new class and initialize the properties
                    select new SampleObject
                    {
                        // the grouping item is the .Key (in this case MsfId)
                        MsfId = itemgroup.Key,
                        // the itemgroup is a collection of all grouped items, so you need to select the properties you're interrested in.
                        DcId = itemgroup.Select(i => i.DcId).ToList(),
                        PgId = itemgroup.Select(i => i.PgId).ToList()
                    };

        // show the results in the Output window.
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine($"MsfId: {item.MsfId}");
            // some trick to format a list of strings to one string
            Trace.WriteLine($"PgId: {string.Join(", ", item.PgId.Select(s => Quote(s)))}");
            Trace.WriteLine($"DcId: {string.Join(", ", item.DcId.Select(s => Quote(s)))}");
            Trace.WriteLine("");
        }
    }

    // this method will surround the passed string with quotes.
    private string Quote(string item)
    {
        return "\"" + item + "\"";
    }
}
```

---

results:

```
MsfId: 100
PgId: "abc", "def", "ghi"
DcId: "123", "456", "789"

MsfId: 101
PgId: "abc"
DcId: "123"
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it all with one [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549393(v=vs.100).aspx) using the appropriate overload. [Working Fiddle Here.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e2FENJ)

Note the use of [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx) to concatenate the grouped collections into one.

```
var result = sampleObjects
    .GroupBy(
        o => o.MsfId,
        (k, g) => new SampleObject
            {
                MsfId = k,
                PgId = g.SelectMany(p => p.PgId).ToList(),
                DcId = g.SelectMany(p => p.DcId).ToList()
            });
```

If you want to remove duplicates from the collections consider [`Distinct()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx) e.g.

```
var result = sampleObjects
    .GroupBy(
        o => o.MsfId,
        (k, g) => new SampleObject
            {
                MsfId = k,
                PgId = g.SelectMany(p => p.PgId).Distinct().ToList(),
                DcId = g.SelectMany(p => p.DcId).Distinct().ToList()
            });
```

Comment: Just tested your solution, the `SelectMany` doesn't work in this case. Within the GroupBy statement, the `g` isn't a list of lists, so you cannot flatten anything. Just change it to `Select()` for a working solution. _(and a +1)_

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen doesn't this depend on the type of `sampleObjects`, presumably you are using an `IEnumerable<SampleObject>` as the `source`?

Comment: This does not work because `SelectMany(p => p.PgId)` returns an `IEnumerable<char>`. Test your solution before posting please.

Comment: @Abbondanza, as I said, it depedends on the type of `sampleObjects`, I've attached a working fiddle to the answer so you can test your comments.

Comment: The OP wasn't very clear about the input type, but I suppose the two example lists represent input and output. If you check the first example list, you will see that it doesn't fit your assumptions.

Comment: @Abbondanza, just going with the class definition, as you say, its ambiguous.

Comment: I think the input is clear: `MsfId: 100 _ PgId: "def" _ DcId: "456"`  PgId doesn't look like a list.

Comment: I'm not interested in an extending a pointless discussion, All that matters is what the OP thinks. The input is not clear, to assert otherwise is blinkered. How would the OP have shown a `List<string>` with 1 item. We can't say for sure. Unless the OP clarifies this is essentially a dead debate and an unanswerable question.